# mock-server: How to delete the expectation

Tags: mockserver

I have a expectation created in mock-server

```
{
  "httpRequest": {
    "method": "GET",
    "path": "/view2/id",
    "queryStringParameters": {
      "id": [
        "1021901022"
      ]
    }
   },
  "httpResponse": {
      "statusCode": 200,
    "body": "Able to fetch-1021901022 "
  }
}
```

How do I delete or update. Tried to send DELETE call to http://hostname:8080/mockserver/expectation but not able to delete

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to jump so fast. Figured out, we have to use the following endpoint to delete

```
curl -v -X PUT "http://localhost:1080/mockserver/clear?type=expectations" -d '{
    "path": "/view2/id"
}'
```